# Replace characters like č,š,ć in a string to their html codes C++

Tags: html, c++

I am using cpprest `http_client` to get the data from RSS link.

the data i revieve is stored as below :

```
container_buffer<std::string> buffer;
response.body().read_to_end(buffer).get();
//use buffer.collection() to get data;
```

And than pass it to drawing lib which take `const char *`.

Now if the data is received is in korean such as

> **지방 아파트 분양시장 `양극화**

It is displayed fine.

but if the data is in crotain or slovak etc.

> oblačno s kišom i pljuskovima, moguć

the characters

> č,š,ć

Are displayed as

> < ? >

now following are things i have tried :

1. I have gcc 4.8.1 so `std::codecvt` is not supported. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37021015/conversion-facets-in-gcc-4-8-1)
2. if i try to store the data in string directly i.e.

   *std::string data;

   data = response.extract_string().get();*

   The crotain or slovak show properly but korean gets distorted.
3. if i try to replace č,š,ć to their html code :

   boost::replace_all(str, "æ", "& aelig;"); // space added otherwise shown as æ here nly

   boost::replace_all(str, "ž", "& #382;");

   boost::replace_all(str, "š", "& scaron;");

   boost::replace_all(str, "è", "& egrave;");

Same like previous these characters are shown correctly but it hinders with the korean characters as well and replaces certain korean characters to these.

How can shall i approach so that i can display all the characters correctly?

Comment: Nothing in your post describes what steps you're taking to handle encoding, code pages, etc.  If you have a series of bytes that fall outside the ASCII range, then you can't do anything with them in terms of text processing unless you know what character set, encoding etc. you're dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't really give all the sufficient details in your question, but it's likely that the reason you are having an issue with some Latin content is because its encoded using one of the `iso-8859` character sets, and your locale's character set is `UTF-8`.

The only approach that displays all characters correctly from the contents of any `HTTP` response:

1) Get the `charset` attribute from the `HTTP` "Content-Type:" header, which will tell you the character set that's used to encode the body of this `HTTP` response.

2) Use a library, such as `libiconv`, to convert the body of the `HTTP` response from the encoded character set to your locale's character set, if your C++ library does not offer a comparable set of locale conversions.

It's been my experience that using `libiconv` is more reliable, since the `C++` standard does not make a lot of guarantees as to which locales are supported.

Comment: The `response.headers().content_type()` gives me result as **text/xml** for [link](http://www.b92.net/info/rss/novo.xml) , do i need to use any other api to get the char set?

Comment: Well, viewing the page source of that link shows that the encoding is "windows-1250".  You need to investigate how to retrieve that value.

Comment: The reference to windows-1250 is from an XML processing directive. For text/xml, UTF-8 is the default encoding content.